# Rails_Admin user control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-admin

Is there any way I can restrict certain users to only be able to see their own content in rails_admin?

Basically say there was a group of Scout leaders for instance within a geographic division, I would like to have many leaders and then only allow them to see the items that they have created.

Would I need to assign them a geo id, and then add that to devise?

Answer (score 3):

I usually use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to do this. You can add checks if a related user is the current user.

Example of a CanCan config for rails admin (ability.rb), for elaborate example see [rails_admin wiki on CanCan](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCan):

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user
      can :access, :rails_admin
      if user.role? :employee
        can :read, [Model1, Model2, Model3]
        can :update, User, :id => user.id #employee can update own user details
      elsif user.role? :admin
        can :manage, :all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And to check the role agains your users, add/change the following in your user model

```
# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role

  def role_enum
    %w[admin employee]
  end

 def role?(role)
   self.role == role.to_s
 end
```